# Disable a field in HTML form using Javascript depend on a chosen value from a dropdown list

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript.  I tried searching sites to figure this out myself but  I was unsuccessful.  I am creating a form using HTML and Javascript.

I am stuck on the following, not sure what am I missing:

User will choose a country, depending on what the user will select, I need to disable United State field or City/Province field.

If the user selects "United States" from id="txtCountries" then the id="txtCustomerStates" remains enabled and id="txtCityProvince" disabled.

If the user selects any other country and not "United States" then vice versa need to happen -  id="txtCustomerStates" disabled and id="txtCityProvince" enabled.

Currently - no matter what the choice is, txtCityProvince is enabled and txtCustomerStates is disabled.

The following is what I did: Javascript file - file name disable.js:

```
//If user selects "United States" - City/Province (International) will be disabled
//If user does not selects "United States - State (USA) will be disabled

function disableState() {
    if (document.getElementById("txtCountries").value === "United States") 
    {
        // document.getElementById("txtCustomerStates").disabled='false';
        document.getElementById("txtCityProvince").disabled='true';
    }
    else  
    {
        // document.getElementById("txtCityProvince").disabled='false';
        document.getElementById("txtCustomerStates").disabled='true';
    } 
}
```

The HTML file:
Countries Section:

```
<div id="divCountries" class="fieldRow">
<div class="leftLabel labelWidth20">
<label for="txtcountries">Country:</label>
</div>
 <div class="LeftField">
   <div class="formField34">
     <select id="txtCountries" type="text" name="Countries" alt="Countries"   
     title="Countries" onchange="javascript:disableState();">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
       <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
       <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
       <option value="UnitedStates">United States</option>
      </select>
    </div>
 </div>
```

United States Section:

```
 <div class="leftLabel labelWidth20">
 <label for="txtCustomerStates">State (USA):</label>
 </div>
 <div class="LeftField">
 <div class="formField40">
  <select id="txtCustomerStates" type="text" name="State" alt="United 
   States" title="United States">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
      <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
      <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
      <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
      <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  </div>
```

The non United States section:

```
<div id="divCityProvince" class="fieldRow">
 <div class="leftLabel labelWidth20">
  <label for="txtCityProvince">City/Province/Town<br>(International):  
  </label>
</div>
<div class="formField34">
<input id="txtCityProvince" type="text" class="textfield" 
 alt="City/Province/Town (International)" title="City/Province/Town 
 (International)">
 </div>  
</div>
```

Thank you in advance for your help,
IS

Answer (score 1):

The whole solution :)
Only javascript section is modified.

```
<div id="divCountries" class="fieldRow">
<div class="leftLabel labelWidth20">
<label for="txtcountries">Country:</label>
</div>
 <div class="LeftField">
   <div class="formField34">
     <select id="txtCountries" type="text" name="Countries" alt="Countries"   
     title="Countries" onchange="disableState()">
       <option value=""></option>
       <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
       <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
       <option value="Algeria">Algeria</option>
       <option value="UnitedStates">United States</option>
      </select>
    </div>
 </div>

 <div class="leftLabel labelWidth20">
 <label for="txtCustomerStates">State (USA):</label>
 </div>
 <div class="LeftField">
 <div class="formField40">
  <select id="txtCustomerStates" type="text" name="State" alt="United 
   States" title="United States">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
      <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
      <option value="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
      <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
      <option value="Arkansas">Arkansas</option>
   </select>
  </div>
  </div>


<div id="divCityProvince" class="fieldRow">
 <div class="leftLabel labelWidth20">
  <label for="txtCityProvince">City/Province/Town<br>(International):  
  </label>
</div>
<div class="formField34">
<input id="txtCityProvince" type="text" class="textfield" 
 alt="City/Province/Town (International)" title="City/Province/Town 
 (International)">
 </div>  
</div>

<script>
function disableState() {

    if (document.getElementById("txtCountries").value === "UnitedStates") 
    {
       document.getElementById("txtCustomerStates").disabled=false;
        document.getElementById("txtCityProvince").disabled='true';

    }
    else  
    {
    document.getElementById("txtCityProvince").disabled=false;        
    document.getElementById("txtCustomerStates").disabled='true';

    } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you all - it worked - I am very appreciative of the help and the fast response.  IS

Comment: if you like any solution, just vote it .... so that the others can find it easily

Answer (score 0):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/Lcu4jp91/)

That was because the value that was returned from `document.getElementById("txtCountries").value` was `UnitedStates` and not `United States`.

Please note that the option for United States was as follows

```
<option value="UnitedStates">United States</option>
```

Notice that there is no space between the `United` and `States` in the value.

**JS**

```
function disableState() {
  if (document.getElementById("txtCountries").value === "UnitedStates") {
    document.getElementById("txtCityProvince").disabled = 'true';
  } else {
    document.getElementById("txtCustomerStates").disabled = 'true';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

Put a space in `value="UnitedStates"`:

```
<option value="United States">United States</option>
```